# Angular Observable error handling with async

Tags: angular

I have a service that collects data and a component to show it the code is as follows:

books.service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Book} from '../model/book';

@Injectable()
export class BooksService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  findAllBooks(): Observable<Book[]> {
    return this.http.get<Book[]>('api/books');
  }

}
```

list-books.component.ts:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {BooksService} from '../../services/books.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Book} from '../../model/book';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-books',
  templateUrl: './list-books.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-books.component.css']
})
export class ListBooksComponent implements OnInit {

  books: Observable<Book[]>;

  constructor(private booksService: BooksService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.books = this.booksService.findAllBooks();
  }
}
```

list-books.component.html:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
  <tr *ngFor="let book of books | async">
    <td>
      {{book.title}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now I would like to handle HTTP Errors (e.g. 404). But I don't know how to properly add error handler without adding subscribe function.

Comment: What do you want to happen on an error? Retry the request, show a message, show no books?

Comment: In this example I would just like to return predefined list of books but probably best would be to show message

Comment: If you want to return some default list, you can do it in the `BooksService`. If you want to show an error message, you need to subscribe in the controller and handle the error. `async` pipe doesn't know how you want to handle the error...

Comment: I solved it. I replaced `// handle the errore` from @Sachila to `of(booksMock)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the `catchError` to handle the errors.

```
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

findAllBooks(): Observable<Book[]> {
    return this.http.get<Book[]>('api/books').pipe(
      catchError(error =>  // handle the errore)
    )
  }
```

Comment: and if I would like to return a predefined list of `Book[]` (let's say it's in `booksMock` variable)?

Comment: I solved it. I had to replace `// handle the errore` with `of(booksMock)`

Comment: I was doing exactly that, but it doesn't seem to work. I have a MyObjectService class which calls the server to retrieve MyObject, and handles errors with a console.log() and then a toastr. The console.log() is called but the toastr message never shows...